# Trigger onClick function from within conditional content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the following code. Inside the ContentTwo component, there is a button, I want it to be able to trigger the same function as the button in the render, when it is the live content. How would I go about this?

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

      // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }

   handleClick() {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
              isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
       }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div >
                 {this.state.isToggleOn ? <ContentOne /> : <ContentTwo />}
                 <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Swap</button>
             </div>
         );
     }
     }
     function ContentOne(props) {
         return(<h1>Content One</h1>
          );
     }

     function ContentTwo(props) {
          return(<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Swap like the other button</button>
          );
     }

      ReactDOM.render(
             <Toggle />,
             document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the this.handleClick to ContentTwo and access it from the props:

```
 <ContentTwo handleClick={this.handleCLick} />
```

and then

```
 function ContentTwo(props) {
      return(<button onClick={props.handleClick}>Swap like the other button</button>
      );
```

Comment: hrmm. No error, but no swap. Any idea of what I did wrong here?
https://codepen.io/picktatar/pen/yLoqYPX

Comment: You have a typo on handlEclick, you forgot the E

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you very much - this answers perfectly.

Comment: no worries, typos are classical, could only recommend to use ts to avoid them though :)